# Trouble including external code snippet into ReactJS component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have a reactJS website and would like to insert external JS and html into my reactJS.

**Here is what I would like to insert into my ReactJS:**

```
<div id="mni-membership-637120971595058361"></div>
<script src="https://greaterpoconochamber.chambermaster.com/Content/Script/Member.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     new MNI.Widgets.Member("mni-membership-637120971595058361",{member:877,styleTemplate:"#@id{text-align:center;position:relative}#@id .mn-widget-member-name{font-weight:700}#@id .mn-widget-member-logo{max-width:100%}"}).create();
</script>
```

**Here is React component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AboutUs  extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="wrap">
                 <h1>Code Snippet</h1>
                 {/*I would like the code here*/}

                 <div id="mni-membership-637120971595058361"></div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AboutUs;
```

**What I have tried so far:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AboutUs  extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        var aScript = document.createElement('script');
        aScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        aScript.src = "https://greaterpoconochamber.chambermaster.com/Content/Script/Member.js";

        document.head.appendChild(aScript);

        aScript.onload = function() {
            alert(MNI); //This is undefined, but it exists in the external JS file.
            //new MNI.Widgets.Member("mni-membership-637120971595058361",{member:877,styleTemplate:"#@id{text-align:center;position:relative}#@id .mn-widget-member-name{font-weight:700}#@id .mn-widget-member-logo{max-width:100%}"}).create();
        };

      }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="wrap">
                 <h1>Code Snippet</h1>
                 {/*I would like the code here*/}

                 <div id="mni-membership-637120971595058361"></div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AboutUs;
```

**I get the following Error:**

> ./src/Components/pages/aboutPage.js   Line 17:19:  'MNI' is not
>   defined  no-undef
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
>
> The div needs to be rendered before the JavaScript is executed.
>
> Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't try to do this with JS. You already have the HTML script tags to use the library; just put that in your main HTML file.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk why is that? I think don't think that's inherently better, maybe just more familiar. doing it JS gives more control of when it can be loaded (though, sure maybe unnecessary)

Comment: @Stivan did you try `alert(window.MNI);`?

Comment: @azium More control over when it loads is not always better. Many third-party libraries are coded expecting to be loaded at particular times (before the body, after the body, etc.) and loading them manually at a different time can break them. More generally, though, manual loading via JS-based DOM injection gives far more places you can accidentally break something on your own.